# Determinant of symmetric $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $M$ be a symmetric $4 \times 4$ matrix and write it as a $2 \times 2$ block matrix
$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}
$. Suppose that $\det(C) = 0$.

What can we say about the determinant of $M$? Ideally I would like $\det(M)$ to be a square. When does that occur?

EDIT: The entries in $M$ are linear forms with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. When I say that determinant should be a square, I mean as a polynomial, not as a number.

Comment: If $C=0, \det B\ne 0$ then $\det M$ cannot be a square.

Comment: @Minz, then $\det(M) = -\det(B)^2$, which is a square over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: all numbers in $\mathbb C$ are squares

Comment: @Minz, I have updated the question now. I am interested in square polynomials.

Comment: then I believe the devil only knows.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the problem, but assume the entries of $M$ to be distinct indeterminates. Then if $x$ is an indeterminate, we have
\begin{equation}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & x & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
= x,
\end{equation}
so in general $\det(M)$ does not appear to be a square.